# Angular function to keep datas doesnt work

Tags: angularjs

I am very new in Angular.js. I am not able to keep data in one array. This array is in a file called controllers.js and the data come from index.html. It's a small form.

```
<html >
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">                
</head>

<body ng-app="miApp" ng-controller="alumnosCtrl">
    <h1>Cuardeno de alumnos</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="alumno in alumnos">
        <p>{{ alumno.nombre}} - {{ alumno.telefono}}</p>
        <p>{{ alumno.curso}}</p>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <h2>Añadir Contacto</h2>
        Nombre: <input type="text" ng-model="nuevoAlumno.alumno"/>
        Telefono: <input type="text" ng-model="nuevoAlumno.telefono" />
        Curso: <input type="text" ng-model="nuevoAlumno.curso" />
        <input type="button" value="Guardar" ng-click="guardar()" />
    </div>

    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</body>
```

**File controller.js**

```
angular.module('miApp',[])         
     .controller("alumnosCtrl", function ($scope) {                                        
                $scope.alumnos = [
                        {nombre: "Francisco Enrique", telefono: "606760428", curso: "Primero" },
                        {nombre: "Hector Merino", telefono: "6067441545", curso: "Segundo" },
                        {nombre: "Jonas Pacheco", telefono: "606458792", curso: "Tercero" }                
                ];                  
                $scope.guardar=function() {                            
                        $scope.alumnos.push({nombre: nuevoAlumno.alumno, telefono: nuevoAlumno.telefono, curso: nuevoAlumno.curso});                          
                                            };
});
```

The new data has to appear with the rest of the datas. Netbeans tells me that the var nuevoAlumno is not defined.

Thanks.

Comment: So where do you define `nuevoAlumno`?

Comment: You should be using $scope.nuevoAlumno in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans is correct, You haven't defined `nuevoAlumno` anywhere.

You need to do:

```
$scope.nuevoAlumno = 
{
  alumno : '',
  telefono : '',
  curso : ''
};
```

Then in `guardar` you need to change your references to `$scope.nuevoAlumno`.

Comment: It stil doesn't work. The console tells me "Cannot set property 'nuevoAlumno' of undefined". I added the new variable into the function "guardar".

Comment: Thanks so much!! I figured out! I added to the fucntion each variable and with this.newVariable.